# Can fractions be written as over 1?

Tags: arithmetic, fractions

I know that all whole numbers can be written as the whole number divided by one. I was wondering if fractions could be written the same way, for example..

Can $1\over2$ be written as

$1/2\over1$

Or $2\over3$ as

$2/3\over1$

If we wanted to solve this problem,

$3 \times 1/2$

Could it be done this way?

${3\over1} \times {1/2\over1} = {(3/2)\over1}$

Comment: Sure! You can always divide by 1. Or multiply by 1. Or add 0... :-)

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_fraction for a different (and more interesting) take.

Answer (score 3):

Of course! All real numbers, when divided by one, equal the number itself. This is true regardless of how the real number is expressed, whether it be a fraction, a mixed number, or any other representation.

Answer (score 1):

A rational number (or fraction) is defined as a whole number divided by a whole number.  So yes, you can.